# Qual a origem do termo "panelinha" para um grupo fechado de pessoas?

Tags: etimologia, origem, substantivos, termos

“Panelinha” é um termo usado para um grupo fechado de pessoas, ou seja, um grupo que não é receptivo quanto a novos membros, sendo mais comum ser usado para um grupo informal, como de colegas de curso, trabalho, etc.

Mas qual a relação de “panela” com isso? Seria porque a panela tem “paredes” e assim o “conteúdo” (membros) fica isolado das “coisas externas" (outras pessoas)? Ou minha lógica está furada... de novo?

Comment: Eu só conhecia o termo na expressão *fazer panelinha* (com alguém): agir concertadamente (com alguém) e em oposição a outros. Os dois sentidos parecem claramente relacionados.

Comment: Talvez de 'grupo que come da mesma panela'?

Comment: @Jacinto Faz sentido, pode ser que seja algo relacionado a isso, mesmo.

Comment: Seria um conjunto de paneleiros? Rá!

Comment: Fazer a panelinha a alguem, significa também quando um grupo tenta tramar um individuo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Panelinha*** no sentido de “grupo fechado” parece vir da locução ***fazer panelinha com alguém***, que significa “associar-se a alguém, tramar alguma coisa com alguém), que poderá vir da ideia de “cozinhar e comer em conjunto”.

O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa define ***panelinha***:

> *s. f.* (De *panela* + suf. *inha*) **1.** Dim. de *panela* **2.** *Fam.* Acordo secreto, conluio entre várias pessoas, normalmente para fins pouco honestos. ≈ Tramóia. *Fazer panelinha com alguém; estar de panelinha com alguém*. **3.** Grupo de pessoas que tomam parte nesse acordo. *Pertencer à panelinha.* **4.** Qualquer grupo muito fechado. ≈ Capelinha.

Procurei no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) e no Google Books, e encontrei *panelinha* no sentido de “grupo fechado” apenas a partir do final do século XIX. A primeiro exemplo é de 1872, na [Revista do Instituto Histórico e Geográfico Brasileiro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A2NKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA194&dq=panelinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYzNLF2fzMAhUBPhQKHUfYAPUQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=panelinha&f=false) (ênfase minha; o mapa de Waldzeemüller é o primeiro onde aparece o nome *América*):

> Quanto ás obras em que se occupou da America, cumpre-nos dizer que, fóra da ***panelinha*** de Waldzeemüller, foi Jo. Schöner o primeiro que, publicamente e pela imprensa, aceitou a designação d'aquelle nome

O primeiro dicionário em que encontrei *panelinha* com este sentido, “grupo”, é o de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913 (é possível que apareça também no de 1899, mas eu não tenho o segundo volume). Mas a locução ***fazer panelinha*** aparece em dicionários anteriores, nomeadamente no *Tesouro da Língua Portuguesa* do Frei Domingos Vieira de 1871, no dicionário de António Morais da Silva de 1831, num dicionário anónimo de 1817 e no [*Vocabulario Portuguez & Latino* de Rafael Bluteau de 1720](http://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5Qack-VzxFPJIRQdFSDF6lou468xHtcIfyn62xcRz1HZIKHoBzjGS_1Cnr9PIyiQMwRWc5y2djSFTHBl39hJ7tyOcA0YTv-Ceh7E9zynLBQB7At3rjBFxFF1fDHmumy_XgNZye490AEhuh497459YqpM6AImzFozQRoRPbIIywxSOHs17d2qYFEReQdWgDm4JRJgP4rhO6VyNVgsEC8rth7rV55gEeD6aKfAuaaAbdtwCrHEkfZWsJkpVYIvcREISiMxBKYFU). O dicionário Houaiss indica 1720 como o ano da ocorrência mais antiga do sentido figurado de *panelinha*, portanto deve referir-se a este dicionário do Bluteau (grafia original):

> PANELINHA. Panella pequena de barro. [Tradução em latim.]
>   Panelinha. Dos que se frequentaõ , & praticaõ muyto huns com os outros , costumamos dizer , que fazem panelinha. Fazer panelinha com alguem. [Tradução em latim.]

O dicionário de António Morais da Silva de 1831 já aponta para a ideia de tramóia (murmurações):

> **Panelinha** *s. f.* dimin. de Panella. § *Fazer panelinha com alguém*, frase vulg. Associar-se-lhe, praticar, e conversar familiarmente sobre negócios, ou murmurações.

Em todos estes dicionários, 1720, 1817, 1831 e 1871, *panela* vem também com o significado figurado de “comida”:

> Panela , toma-se vulgarmente pelo comer , e sustento ordinario. Bom he tratar da panela. [Bluteau, 1720.]

Portanto parece-me muito plausível que a locução *fazer panelinha com alguém* no sentido de “associar-se, tramar com alguém” venha da ideia de cozinhar e, por implicação, comer em conjunto, o que implica grande intimidade. Note-se que *cozinhar* tem hoje também o significado de “tramar, maquinar ardilosamente” [(Aulete 6)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cozinhar). Esta ideia está de acordo como uma passagem de 1806-9, que é a primeiro exemplo que eu encontrei de *panelinha* com o significado de “acordo”, e que aparece inserido numa grande metáfora culinária. É um dos muitos despachos curiosos de D. Francisco Mello Manoel da Camara, governador e capitão general do Estado do Maranhão e Grão-Pará de 1806 a 1809, aqui publicado em 1892 na [*Revista trimestral do Instituto Historico e Geográfico Brazileiro*:](https://archive.org/stream/revistadoinstit20unkngoog/revistadoinstit20unkngoog_djvu.txt)

> Por não me saborear bem a panelinha temperada pelo Revdo. Pároco, pelo juiz e seu escrivão, concedo a licença.

Comment: É... Minha lógica está furada de novo. Haushaushaush XD

Comment: @BrunoLopes Acontece quando há vária lógicas possíveis. Possivelmente, nunca tinhas ouvido *fazer panelinha*? Aqui também creio que já não se usa. Eu lembro-me de ouvir o pessoal da geração do meu pai usar.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Ahah! Encontrei a referência de 1720 mencionada no Houaiss! Vou incluir.