# Origem de "para inglês ver"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Diz-se que algo é “para inglês ver” se for só fachada para causar boa impressão. Como por exemplo neste artigo no [Diário de Notícias (3-9-2016)](http://www.dn.pt/portugal/interior/ministro-recusa-investigacoespara-ingles-ver-5416626.html), um jornal português:

> Ministro recusa investigações para “inglês ver”

O artigo refere-se a investigações sobre a morte de dois comandos em exercícios militares. Investigações “para inglês ver”, que o ministro alegadamente recusa, seriam só uma fachada para apaziguar o público, sem intenção de verdadeiramente apurar responsabilidades.

Eu sempre pensei que a expressão tivesse nascido de coisas feitas só para impressionar turistas ingleses em Portugal, e nem sabia se era usada no Brasil. Mas no outro dia descobri que não só é usado no Brasil, como provavelmente foi lá que teve origem. A hipótese mais aceite é que a expressão nasceu da lei Feijó de 1831, que proibia e punia o tráfico de escravos para o Brasil. A lei teria sido aprovada apenas para satisfazer pressões britânicas, e sem qualquer intenção de que viesse a ser aplicada. [Neste site da Prefeitura do Rio de Janeiro](http://www.multirio.rj.gov.br/historia/modulo02/ingles_ver.html) diz-se:

> Comentava-se na Câmara dos Deputados, nas casas e nas ruas, que o Ministro Feijó fizera uma “lei para inglês ver”.

[Este artigo na Veja (17-2-2014)](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/como-nasceu-a-expressao-para-ingles-ver/) acrescenta duas outras hipóteses, recolhidas pelo filólogo Antenor Nascentes. Uma é que os ingleses no Pernambuco se vestiam de linho; quando os pernambucanos, em vez da habitual casimira, vestiam também linho, dir-se-ia que o faziam “para inglês ver”. A outra foi que D. João VI ao chegar à Bahia em 1808 escoltado pela armada britânica, vendo do barco a bonita iluminação da cidade (Salvador?), teria comentado que “está bem bom para o inglês ver”.

Ora para variar, há uma hipótese, a da lei antiesclavagista, que me parece altamente plausível. A maioria dos sites que visitei nem menciona outra. O que é frustrante é que nenhum dos sites que encontrei cita fontes antigas, para já não falar de contemporâneas da lei, ficando-se sem saber como é que se sabe que a expressão nasceu aí.

**Portanto o que eu quero saber é quais são os dados concretos sobre a origem da expressão, nomeadamente:**

- Quais são os exemplos mais antigos de uso da expressão em Portugal e no Brasil? Esses exemplos dão-nos alguma indicação acerca de qual terá sido a origem da expressão? Favorecem alguma das hipóteses anteriores?
- Encontram-se alguns comentários antigos sobre a origem da expressão? Por exemplo, testemunhos de alguém que se lembra de a ouvir neste ou naquele contexto já em tempos recuados; ou de ouvir a avó ou avô contar que a tinha ouvido?

Comment: Só um adendo: no Brasil, "inglês", particularmente entre as camadas mais populares, é uma metonímia para qualquer indivíduo reconhecido como estrangeiro de ascendência europeia. Varia de região para região, mas também se usa _[alemão](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/galego/)_, _[galego](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/galego/)_ e _[polaco](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/polaco/16146/)_ com significado similar. Se a origem é mesmo brasileira, não se prenda(m) muito ao significado literal.

Comment: @RamonMelo, não sabia disso. Mas já procurei pelas origens de muita expressão idiomática, e esta, da lei de 1831, foi das que achei mais convicentes. Agora, o que é preciso é encontrar os primeiros exemplos de uso. Dizer-se, quase dois séculos depois do acontecimento, que se dizia na Câmara isto e aquilo não chega.

Comment: @Jacinto : No Brasil essa história é bem comum. Inclusive na praia de "Porto de Galinhas" cidade Ipojuca no estado do Pernambuco (Brasil), tem o seu nome atrelado a essa história. Isso é contado pelos habitantes e guias turísticos: De que ali era "um Porto de Galinhas apenas para inglês ver", e que na verdade trafegavam escravos. Por fim, tenho que deixar registrado como são belas as praias dessa região de Pernambuco.

Comment: @Luciano Essa hipótese parece-me bem plausível. Mas então devem existir exemplos antigos do uso da expressão, em livros, jornais, etc. Eu vi essa história em imensos sites, mas nenhum diz qualquer coisa do tipo, "O senhor X já dizia em mil oitocentos e tal que...", com referência completa, para podermos ir ver.

Comment: No google books a obra mais antiga que encontro contendo a expressão é de 1882 - os "Annaes" da Câmara dos Deputados. Claro que isso não pode responder à questão a respeito da origem da expressão.

Comment: verbete Lei para inglês ver no dicionário da Escravidão Negra no Brasil do Clóvis Moura https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-br&id=6Zcz0fIj91cC&q=ingl%C3%AAs+ver#v=snippet&q=ingl%C3%AAs%20ver&f=false

Comment: @Lambie, essa parece ser fonte mais fiável que vi até agora, mas ainda assim é um livro publicado em 2004, e não encontrei a fundamentação. Poderá possivelmente estar nas páginas não disponíveis no Google.

Comment: @Jacinto os dicionários normalmente são normativos, não explicam a fundamentação. As vezes, como o OED inglês, citam frases de primeiro uso.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o [artigo na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leis_para_ingl%C3%AAs_ver), a expressão remonta ao tempo da escravatura, quando, após terem findado com a escravatura, os Ingleses impuseram aos seus aliados, entre os quais o Brasil, que estes também a abolissem.

O regente D. Pedro II, pressionado a agradar aos ingleses que eram seus parceiros comerciais, promulgou então uma lei em 1831, que declarava livres os africanos desembarcados em portos brasileiros desde aquele ano. Mas o sentimento geral era de que a lei não seria cumprida, fazendo-se circular pela Corte e Câmara dos Deputados, o comentário de que seria apenas uma lei só "para inglês ver".

Outras [fontes](https://www.significados.com.br/para-ingles-ver/) também atestam esta teoria.

Comment: Essa tese, de origem na lei Feijó de 1831, já eu apresento na pergunta. Sim, encontramos essa tese por todo o lado na internet. Mas não é isso que eu pergunto. Vê os últimos três parágrafos da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Jacinto,

Você e o João no meu ponto de vista estão corretos, pois é exatamente pelos motivos já citados que essa expressão começou a ser utilizada. Segundo [a matéria do G1 com o professor Paulo Chaves](http://g1.globo.com/pernambuco/educacao/noticia/2016/10/leis-para-ingles-ver-antecederam-abolicao-da-escravatura-no-brasil.html):

> Antes de abolir definitivamente a escravidão no Brasil, o governo de Dom Pedro II aprovou uma série de leis apenas para dar satisfação à Inglaterra, que no início do século 19 passou a combater o tráfico de escravos no Oceano Atlântico. Sob forte pressão daquele país, que havia se tornado uma potência industrializada e exercia sobre o mundo um grande domínio mercadológico, o Brasil acabou tendo que ceder.
>
> O professor de História Paulo Chaves explica que a industrialização da Inglaterra provocou uma mudança econômica importante no mundo, já que, para ela, era fundamental subverter a escravidão em trabalho assalariado nas áreas americanas.
>
> "Em 1845, a Inglaterra cria uma lei chamada 'Bill Aberdeen', que permite que frotas britânicas naveguem pelo Atlântico para fiscalizar o tráfico negreiro intercontinental. Caso um navio chamado 'tumbeiro' fosse avistado e sob suspeita de tráfico negreiro, esse navio então seria interceptado pela Marinha Britânica e, confirmada a presença de negros, esses escravos seriam devolvidos para a África. O navio seria, então, confiscado e incorporado à Marinha Britânica e o capitão preso", salienta o professor.
>
> Do ponto de vista comercial e diplomático, a Inglaterra passa a pressionar o governo de Dom Pedro II, até que em 1850 é aprovada no Brasil a 'Lei Eusébio de Queirós', que proíbe internamente a prática do tráfico negreiro.
>
> Em 1871, a 'Lei do Ventre Livre', que é considerada a primeira lei abolicionista da história do Brasil, determinava que todos os escravos nascidos a partir daquela data, de mães escravas, seriam libertados. Nessa mesma lei, no seu artigo primeiro, se colocava que a criança nascida de mãe escrava deveria permanecer sob a proteção dela e do senhor até completar 9 anos de idade.
>
> A partir daquele momento, caberia ao senhor decidir o futuro daquela criança, podendo vendê-la ao governo brasileiro por 600 contos de réis. Nesse caso, o governo teria o direito de explorar sua mão de obra até os 21 anos, para custear sua alforria, ou o senhor poderia optar por manter o escravo sob seu domínio até os 21 anos. Essas leis, segundo o professor Paulo Chaves, refletiam apenas uma necessidade de o governo brasileiro dar satisfações à Inglaterra e, por isso, eram conhecidas como **'leis para inglês ver'**.
>
> Em 1885, já quase sem mais conseguir sustentar as pressões pela abolição, destaca o professor, o governo brasileiro aprova a 'Lei dos Sexagenários'. "Essa lei consegue ser ainda mais hipócrita do que a 'Lei do Ventre Livre', já que determinava que todos os escravos maiores de 65 anos seriam libertados. Levando em consideração que a estimativa de vida de um escravo no Brasil era de 30 anos, era praticamente impossível um cativo atingir essa idade. E principalmente porque, atingindo, já não era mais uma mão de obra produtiva", pondera.
>
> Não mais conseguindo produzir leis **'para inglês ver'**, o governo de Dom Pedro II, por meio de sua filha, a princesa Isabel, decreta a 'Lei Áurea', que simboliza histórica e juridicamente o fim da escravidão no Brasil.

**Mais referências que fomentam a teoria:**

http://oglobo.globo.com/opiniao/para-ingles-ver-19006175

http://www.ifch.unicamp.br/ojs/index.php/rhs/article/view/912

http://www.teclasap.com.br/how-do-i-say-para-ingles-ver-in-english/

http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/como-nasceu-a-expressao-para-ingles-ver/

http://www.educacao.sp.gov.br/noticias/pra-ingles-ver-confira-a-origem-das-principais-expressoes-populares-brasileiras

https://www.tjrs.jus.br/export/poder_judiciario/historia/memorial_do_poder_judiciario/memorial_judiciario_gaucho/revista_justica_e_historia/issn_1677-065x/v6n12/Microsoft_Word_-_ARTIGO_UMA_LEI_PARA_INGLxS_VER...._Argemiro_gurgel.pdf

Comment: n3, não respondes à pergunta; não sei se a compreendeste; vê por favor os últimos três parágrafos a partir do negrito. O que eu peço são os exemplos mais antigos do uso da expressão. Quero que me digam coisas do tipo, "há esta publicação de 1840 (ou o ano que for) que já usa a expressão" (com link e citação); ou "neste livro de 1860, o autor diz que já em 1835 ouviu a expressão a propósito disto e daquilo" (link e citação). Não peço mais links que simplesmente repetem ou desenvolvem um bocadinho o que eu já apresentei na pergunta.

Comment: Podes ver exemplos disto na pergunta da [panelinha](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3279/qual-a-origem-do-termo-panelinha-para-um-grupo-fechado-de-pessoas) e na da [meia tijela](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/pergunta-da-meia-tigela). Se estiveres interessado em procurar este tipo de coisas, tens também [aqui](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/288/resources-for-etymological-research-recursos-para-investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-etimol%C3%B3gica) links a dicionários antigos e outros recursos, e podes procurar também no Google Books.